# Why parent state is not updating when I change a value on a child but it is working the other way around

Tags: reactjs

In my React App with hooks, I'm having a text field on the parent and child component where I can modify an email. When I modify in parent the email that also updated on the child but from child to parent is not. I cannot resolve this situation.

**Current behavior**

1. From the parent component when updating the email also it is updating the email on the child
2. From the child component when updating the email the parent component is not updating until I refresh

**Expected behavior**

I can update email in both ways

**Code**

Parent sideBar

```
const SideBar = ({
    consentee,
    classes,
    onUpdateRecipient,
    onUpdateConsentee,
  }) => {
    const [isEmailDisabled, setIsEmailDisabled] = useState(true);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState(consentee.primaryRecipient.email);
  
    const handleEmailUpdate = useCallback(() => {
      if (isEmail(email)) {
        setIsEmailDisabled(!isEmailDisabled);
        if (consentee.primaryRecipient.email !== email) {
          onUpdateRecipient({ ...consentee.primaryRecipient, email }, false);
        }
      }
    }, [consentee, email, isEmailDisabled, onUpdateRecipient]);
  
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.main}>
          <div className={classes.row}>
            <EditableText
              label={<FormattedMessage defaultMessage={'Email'} />}
              value={email}
              isDisabled={isEmailDisabled}
              onEdit={() => {
                setIsEmailDisabled(!isEmailDisabled);
              }}
              onChange={setEmail}
              validator={isEmail}
              onBlur={handleEmailUpdate}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
```

Child

```
const RecipientTableRow = ({ classes, row, index, onSave }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(row);
  const [isEditable, setIsEditable] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(row);
    setIsEditable(false);
  }, [row]);

  const toggleEdit = () => {
    setData(row);
    setIsEditable(!isEditable);
  };

  const handleEmailChange = e => {
    const dataCopy = { ...data };
    dataCopy.email = e.target.value;
    setData(dataCopy);
  };

  const saveChanges = useCallback(async () => {
    await onSave(data, index);
    setIsEditable(false);
  }, [onSave, setIsEditable, data, index]);
 
  const isEmailValid = isEmail(data.email);

  let isSaveButtonDisabled =!isEmailValid;

  return (
    <TableRow
      className={`${classes.root} ${
        index % 2 === 0 && !isEditable ? classes.darkBackground : ''
      }`}
    >
      <TableCell align="left">
        <TextField
          error={!isEmailValid}
          variant="filled"
          onChange={handleEmailChange}
          title={data.email}
          disabled={!isEditable}
          value={data.email}
        />
      </TableCell>
      <Visible
        when={isEditable}
        fallBack={<EditButton onToggleEdit={toggleEdit} />}
      >
        <SaveCancelButtons
          onSave={saveChanges}
          onCancel={toggleEdit}
          isSaveButtonDisabled={isSaveButtonDisabled}
        />
      </Visible>
    </TableRow>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where you called `RecipientTableRow`? It would be easier if you could create a demo link of your issue or recreate it on codesandbox

Comment: It is difficult to make this in an example however this is how it is called
https://pastebin.com/c4dmVLHP
but doing console when I change on the child I see on parent `consentee.primaryRecipient.email` which contains my new email but the email inside none so not sure about this useState part

Comment: See if you have imported RecipientsTableBody = ({ data, status, onRecipientUpdate }) => {, then u have to handle onRecipientUpdate in the parent component, please see below anser for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have to update the parent **Parent sideBar** component whenever there is a change in email in the child **RecipientTableRow** component.

Please take reference from the below example:

```
// Child component

function RecipientTableRow({triggerParentUpdate}){
 const onSave = () => {
   triggerParentUpdate(data.email)
  };
}

// parent component
const updateEmail= (email) => {
  setEmail(email);
} 
<RecipientTableRow triggerParentUpdate = {updateEmail} />
```